# How can I update "non-conventional" HTML element properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

How can I update "non-conventional" (not many use cases) HTML element properties dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery or Angular?

I have tried using `[src]="cvv`" (Angular), but it does not seem like I am having much luck. I am not even sure all these properties or attributes can be dynamically updated.

**Example: How update the `action=""` URL and the the `target` property in the form element below?**

```
<form class="wpwl-form" action="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts/EB477281A6AA/payment" method="POST" target="card_1270556498138">
```

**And how can I update the `src` property of the `iframe` below?**

```
<iframe class="wpwl-control" frameborder="0" src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/pciIframe.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute`

```
var b = document.querySelector("button"); 

b.setAttribute("name", "helloButton");
```

Taken from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

You can use the following

```
var form = document.querySelector(".wpwl-form")[0];
var iframe = document.querySelector(".wpwl-control")[0];

form.setAttribute("action", "value for action");
form.setAttribute("target", "value for target");

iframe.setAttribute("src", "value for src");
```

Not in a position to test, but that should work.

Comment: why do we need to use javascript when this is doable with angular only?

Comment: @jitender you realise Angular is javascript right? Also did you read the question _"How can I update "non-conventional" (not many use cases) HTML element properties dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery or Angular?"_

Comment: @jitender the question is not specific to angular, user has asked the ways to do this in javascript/jquery/angular.

Comment: @Hemendra don't guide someone to wrong path if he don't know the right path

Comment: @jitender you haven't read the question in it's entirety and commented your answer in this post, when this question could easily be a duplicate of 100's of other questions.

Comment: @jitender just because it's not the path you chose, doesn't make it the wrong path. My solution is vanilla JavaScript which will work in jQuery, Angular, and JavaScript. It also will work with AngularJs and Angulsr2+, which op didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in angular property binding here like

```
<form class="wpwl-form" [action]="url" method="POST" [target]="target">
```

where `url` and `target` are properties defined in component.ts like

```
url='https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts/EB477281A6AA/payment';
target='card_1270556498138'
```

[check this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvzsps)

Answer (score 0):

With Angular you can bind HTML properties to a variable, updating this variable will update the property.
In your example you should use [action] and [src] instead of of action and src.

example:
`<iframe class="wpwl-control" frameborder="0" [src]="myIframSrc"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular you should not use action tag in form element instead you should do in angular way.When binding url in src angular will consider a url as a unsafe URL.To make sure your are binding safe url you should use [DomSanitizer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angula-iframe-1) so mark the url safe.

**component.ts**

```
 srcUrl: string = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fdf5aTYRW0E";
  safeUrl;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    const url = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, this.safeUrl);
     this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.srcUrl);
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angula-iframe-1)

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference variable to your iframe and access it using ViewChild in your ts file.
Using that variable , you can modify the attributes.

```
 <iframe #ifrme style="height: 400px;width:400px" frameborder="0" src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/pciIframe.html"></iframe>

 ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.ifrme.nativeElement.src= "https://www.niceonecode.com/";
  }
```